# How do I deal with this error when trying to import Python Flask-Compress

Tags: python, flask, gzip

I want to serve compressed files from my flask application, and I looked around and found this solution.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.compress import Compress

app = Flask(__name__)
Compress(app)
```

This is what is says on the docs, but when I try and actually implement this I get an error.

```
Cannot find reference 'compress' in '__init__.py' less... (⌘F1) 
This inspection detects names that should resolve but don't. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Top-level and class-level items are supported better than instance items.
```

And consequently I cannot import Compress.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue and possibly an alternative way to compress the files on my web app.

I have imported the modules into Pycharm correctly as my IDE shows that they have been installed. Its just when I try and do the above in my application that I get this error.

### Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from the README of [flask-compress](https://github.com/jmcarp/flask-compress/blob/master/README.md).

> In many cases, one cannot expect a Flask instance to be ready at import time, and a common pattern is to return a Flask instance from within a function only after other configuration details have been taken care of. In these cases, Flask-Compress provides a simple function, init_app, which takes your application as an argument.

Did you try using this?

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_compress import Compress

compress = Compress()

def start_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    compress.init_app(app)
    return app
```

Also, I would recommend using the new Flask import standard for all of your imports, so

```
from flask_compress import Compress
```

instead of the old

```
from flask.ext.compress import Compress
```

Answer (score -1):

I use [`zipfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) to compress files. From the Introduction:

> The ZIP file format is a common archive and compression standard. This module provides tools to create, read, write, append, and list a ZIP file. Any advanced use of this module will require an understanding of the format, as defined in PKZIP Application Note.

and with `ZipFile.write(filename)` you can write files to a ZipFile object representing the archive.